# If statement with nested if not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I made a game with HTML canvas in which the user can control the movement of a character. I'd like the following outer `if` statement to first reset the x and y positions of the character, then if the user is out of lives, call a function that opens a modal and disable keydown events. Instead, the function is called, opening the modal, and movement on the board ceases (the moving enemy characters stop moving); however, the x and y positions are not set to what is specified in the outer if statement, which I expect to occur before anything in the nested `if` statement. Without the statement removing the event listener, it works as expected (the x and y values are set then the modal is opened).

```
if (player.x < this.x + 70 && player.x + 17 > this.x && player.y < this.y + 45 && 30 + player.y > this.y) {
  player.x = 200;
  player.y = 400;
  lives--;
  sidebarLives.innerHTML = lives;
  modalScore.innerHTML = score;
  if (lives === 0) {
    // Calls function that adds class that sets modal to display: block
    showModal();
    // This prevents player x and y values from updating (though modal appears)
    document.removeEventListener('keydown');
  }
}
```

Link to game: https://nataliecardot.com/arcade-game/index.html

Here's my full JS code:

```
"use strict"; // Enables strict mode to catch common bloopers

// TODO: Disable player movement when modal opened? Also, set 3 tries before modal opened (change to game over). Restart button.

const playAgainButton = document.querySelector('.play-again');
const restartButton = document.querySelector('.restart');

// Calls playAgain() function when user clicks play again button in modal
playAgainButton.addEventListener('click', playAgain);

// Calls playAgain() function when user clicks reset icon in sidebar
restartButton.addEventListener('click', playAgain);

// Starts lives at 3
let lives = 3;

let sidebarLives = document.querySelector('.lives-left');
sidebarLives.innerHTML = lives;

// Sets an initial player score of 0.
let score = 0;
// Sets score shown in sidebar
// document.getElementsByClassName('score')[0].innerHTML = score;
let sidebarScore = document.querySelector('.score');
sidebarScore.innerHTML = score;

let modalScore = document.querySelector('.modal-score');
modalScore.innerHTML = score;

// These 2 lines were used to set star rating in modal
// let starRating = document.querySelector('.stars').innerHTML;
// document.getElementsByClassName('star-rating')[0].innerHTML = starRating;

// Called when user clicks restart button in sidebar or play again button in modal. Sets modal to display: none, resets lives and score
function playAgain() {
  // Hides modal if present (if opened by game ending)
  modal.classList.remove('modal-visible');
  lives = 3;
  sidebarLives.innerHTML = lives;
  score = 0;
  sidebarScore.innerHTML = score;
}

// Calls playAgain() function (hides modal and restarts game) with user clicks "play again" button in modal
// TODO: remove? just one event listener for both buttons?
// modalPlayAgainButton.addEventListener('click', playAgain);

// Note: In a constructor function "this" does not have a value. It is a substitute for the new object. The value of this will become the new object when a new object is created

// Note commas not used to separate methods and properties in a class
class Player {
  // Constructor function, a special function just for initializing new objects, will automatically run when a new object is constructed (with keyword "new") from this class. Contains data needed to create it
  constructor(x, y, speed) {
    this.sprite = 'images/char-boy.png';
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = speed;
  }

  // Methods that all objects created from class will inherit. Would exist on prototype in pre-class way of writing it, but effect is the same (the following methods still exist on Player prototype [for example would be Player.prototype.update = function(dt)...])

  // When player reaches water, moves player back to starting position, and increase score by 1
  update(dt) {
    if (this.y === 25) {
      this.x = 200;
      this.y = 400;
      score++;
      sidebarScore.innerHTML = score;
    }
  }

  // Draws player on screen
  render() {
    ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), this.x, this.y)
  }

  // Connects keyboard input to player movement. If statements prevent player movement off screen
  handleInput(allowedKeys) {

    if (allowedKeys === 'down' && this.y < 425) {
      this.y += 25;
    }

        if (allowedKeys === 'up') {
            this.y -= 25;
        }

        if (allowedKeys === 'left' && this.x > 0) {
            this.x -= 25;
        }

        if (allowedKeys === 'right' && this.x < 400) {
            this.x += 25;
        }
  }
}

class Enemy {
// Sets enemy's initial location
  constructor(x, y, speed) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    // Sets speed of enemy
    this.speed = speed;
    // The image/sprite for our enemies
    this.sprite = 'images/enemy-bug.png';
  }

  update(dt) {
    // Multiplies enemy's movement by time delta to ensure game runs at same speed for all computers
    this.x += this.speed * dt;
    // Once enemy finished moving across screen, moves it back so it can cross screen again and randomizes its speed
    if (this.x > 500) {
      this.x = -75;
      // Math.random() function returns random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). Math.floor() returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number
      this.speed = 70 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 450);
    }

    // When collission occurs, subtracts a life, updates lives displayed in sidebar and updates score that will be displayed in modal if no lives remaining
    if (player.x < this.x + 70 && player.x + 17 > this.x && player.y < this.y + 45 && 30 + player.y > this.y) {
        player.x = 200;
        player.y = 400;
      lives--;
      sidebarLives.innerHTML = lives;
      modalScore.innerHTML = score;
      if (lives === 0) {
        // Calls function that adds class that sets modal to display: block
        showModal();
        // This prevents player x and y values from updating (though modal appears)
        document.removeEventListener('keydown');
      }
    }
  }

  // Draws enemy on the screen
  render() {
    ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), this.x, this.y);
  }
};


// ENEMY/PLAYER OBJECT INSTANTIATION

let enemyPosition = [60, 140, 220];

let allEnemies = [];

let player = new Player(200, 400, 50);

enemyPosition.forEach(function(posY) {
  let enemy = new Enemy(0, posY, 70 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 450));
  allEnemies.push(enemy);
});

// Modal

const modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
const closeIcon = document.querySelector('.close');

// When called, adds class that sets modal to display: block when player reaches water
function showModal() {
  modal.classList.add('modal-visible');
}

// Closes modal (adding class that sets it back to display: none) upon user's clicking its close icon
closeIcon.addEventListener('click', function() {
  modal.classList.remove('modal-visible');
});

// Closes modal and restarts game when key is pressed down (note: keydown used instead of keypress because keypress only works for keys that produce a character value)
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  let keyCode = e.keyCode;
  if (keyCode === 27) {
    modal.classList.remove('modal-visible');
    playAgain()
  }
});

// Listens for keydown event (fired when a key is pressed down [regardless of whether it produces a character, unlike keypress]) and sends the keys to Player.handleInput() method
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  let allowedKeys = {
    37: 'left',
    38: 'up',
    39: 'right',
    40: 'down'
  };
  // Not sure why "player" needs to be lowercase, given the class name is uppercase
  player.handleInput(allowedKeys[e.keyCode]);
});
```

Comment: What _are_ the values of `x` and `y` once you're inside the nested `if`? Are they close to your reset values, or are they closer to the values you had _before_ entering the outer `if`?

Comment: What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Is the value of `this` what you expect to be ?

Comment: I believe [removeEventListener](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) requires the function to be removed as its second argument (though I don't think that's causing the unexpected behavior).

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: I'm using Windows, and the same behavior occurs in Firefox and Chrome. Thank you for the suggestion, I'll look into it.

Comment: Try moving the letdown eventListener handler functions out so they aren’t anonymous and have file scope. Then supply the same function as the second argument to window.removeEventListener(‘keydown’, ...)

Comment: You have 2 'keydown' event listeners, which one to remove? In `player.handleInput(allowedKeys[e.keyCode]);` you need the lowercase because you need an instance of the `Player` class.

Comment: The allowed keys is the one I'd like to remove. My goal is to disable arrow keys while the modal is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.removeEventListener` function has 2 parameters (event name and listener function) and neither of them is optional. Listener function in your case is the function that you used when adding keydown event listener. So calling `document.removeEventListener` with only 1 argument causes typeerror and enemy's render function won't execute.